# ArrayList keeps resetting after loop. what am I doing wrong?

Tags: java, arrays, loops, arraylist, while-loop

Everytime I loop through the arrayList, it resets itself. Eventually the goal is to make a program that finds the mean of numbers in an arrayList

```
public class loops {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Do you want to calculate the most reoccuring answer?");
        System.out.println("enter 'yes' or 'no'");

        Scanner start = new Scanner(System. in );
        String starter = start.nextLine();
        boolean jax = true;

        while (jax == true && starter.equals("yes")) {
            Scanner answer = new Scanner(System. in );
            System.out.println("Enter the answer choice");
            int ans = answer.nextInt();

            ArrayList < Integer > max = new ArrayList < Integer > ();
            max.add(ans);

            Scanner goOn = new Scanner(System. in );
            System.out.println("Any other grades?");
            System.out.println("yes or no");
            String procced = goOn.nextLine();
            String str12 = "yes";
            String str113 = "no";


            if (procced.equals(str113)) {
                jax = false;
                System.out.print(max);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: New User! We should all post nice answers/comments. Please refrain from downvoting as this is a reasonable question for a beginning Java programmer. Welcome to Stackoverflow! I hope you have a pleasant time asking questions.

Answer (score 3):

You're redeclaring `max` in every iteration of the loop. Move the line

```
ArrayList <Integer> max = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

To be before outside and before the `while` loop.

Comment: Thank you.  I can't believe I did not think of that.  I am fairly new to java and appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2):

```
ArrayList <Integer> max = new ArrayList<Integer>(); 
max.add(ans);
```

everytime you say ArrayList  max = new ArrayList();

you create new arraylist, make sure you do that once and keep adding

Comment: Thank you.  I can't believe I did not think of that.  I am fairly new to java and appreciate the help.